# MAAS is failing to provision a node

Tags: maas, landscape

```
May 20 21:47:13 maas-poc maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: landscape (node-6c1847c0-f8c1-11e4-9204-000c29f54179)
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('10.16.16.106', 1168): <RRQDatagram(filename=bootx64.efi, mode=octet, options={'tsize': '0', 'blksize': '1468'})>
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [-] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 49909
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [-] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb098>
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
            return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
            return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
            return func(*args,**kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
            why = selectable.doRead()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 234, in doRead
            self.protocol.datagramReceived(data, addr)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftp/bootstrap.py", line 171, in datagramReceived
            datagram = TFTPDatagramFactory(*split_opcode(datagram))
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftp/datagram.py", line 394, in __call__
            return datagram_class.from_wire(payload)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftp/datagram.py", line 323, in from_wire
            raise InvalidErrorcodeError(errorcode)
        tftp.errors.InvalidErrorcodeError: Unknown error code: 8

2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('10.16.16.106', 1169): <RRQDatagram(filename=bootx64.efi, mode=octet, options={'blksize': '1468'})>
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [-] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 40380
2015-05-20 21:50:16-0700 [-] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb320>
2015-05-20 21:50:17-0700 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2015-05-20 21:50:17-0700 [-] (UDP Port 40380 Closed)
2015-05-20 21:50:17-0700 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb320>
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [TFTP (UDP)] Datagram received from ('10.16.16.106', 1170): <RRQDatagram(filename=/grubx64.efi, mode=octet, options={'blksize': '512'})>
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [-] RemoteOriginReadSession starting on 57408
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [-] Starting protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb4d0>
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] (UDP Port 49909 Closed)
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb098>
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [RemoteOriginReadSession (UDP)] Final ACK received, transfer successful
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [-] (UDP Port 57408 Closed)
2015-05-20 21:50:18-0700 [-] Stopping protocol <tftp.bootstrap.RemoteOriginReadSession instance at 0x7f9935dbb4d0>
2015-05-20 21:50:19-0700 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 392, in startReactor
            self.config, oldstdout, oldstderr, self.profiler, reactor)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 313, in runReactorWithLogging
            reactor.run()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
            self.mainLoop()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
            self.runUntilCurrent()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftp/util.py", line 80, in _call_and_schedule
            self.callable(*self.callable_args, **self.callable_kwargs)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 254, in write
            return self.socket.send(datagram)
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'Port' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

Comment: Please edit your question by providing the version of MAAS that you are using.

Comment: 1.7 latest stable.

Comment: Please be more specific: dpkg-query -W maas :) And file a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+filebug

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1317705, which is fixed in MAAS 1.8.1.